# Incremental Area Under the Curve (iAUC) in python

Tags: python, area, curve

I have found a way to do this. Previously I have surf through the internet to find a way and couldn't found one. So I have tried on my own and found this. Feel free to mention if there is an error. a is an array of x values, and y is an array of b values

```
    def areaUnderCurve(a, b):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        if (b[i+1]-b[0]>=0) and (b[i]-b[0]>=0):
            temp = ((b[i]-b[0]+b[i+1]-b[0])/2)*(a[i+1]-a[i])
        elif (b[i+1]-b[0] < 0) and (b[i]-b[0] >= 0):
            temp = (b[i]-b[0])*((b[i]-b[0])/(b[i]-b[i+1])*(a[i+1]-a[i])/2)
        elif (b[i+1]-b[0] >= 0) and (b[i]-b[0] < 0):
            temp = (b[i+1]-b[0])*((b[i+1]-b[0])/(b[i+1]-b[i])*(a[i+1]-a[i])/2)
        elif (b[i]-b[0] < 0) and (b[i+1]-b[0] < 0):
            temp = 0
        sum = sum + temp
    return sum
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question

Comment: I have posted this to help someone :)